NX Angular Monorepositori with Capacitor
I am looking to configure capacitor inside my NX Angular monorepo. With the goal of creating a mobile app from my web-app.
The versions I should use are:

NX: 17
Angular: 16

However, it doesn't seem to be working and I can't find an updated working guide. I am currently experiencing a lot of problems with node-modules.
I would like to be able to create the "android" image of the angular base application that 'is inside the monorepo. In some cases I succeeded, but the android image would give errors when I tried to start it with android-studio.
Scaffold:

GitHub

Guides followed:

https://nx.dev/getting-started/tutorials/angular-monorepo-tutorial
https://nxtend.dev/docs/capacitor/getting-started
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started

NB: I tried by installing the latest versions. But even so capacitor doesn't seem to create me an android image of my working webapp.

Do you get specific errors that can lead us? Maybe if the issue is about npm dependency resolution, you could try using yarn instead of npm...
